# Is this something to worry about? The authenticity of wordpress-6.4.3-new-bundled.zip could not be verified as no signature was found

Tags: php, wordpress

I was updating Wordpress and it succeeeded but I saw this warning:

```
The authenticity of wordpress-6.4.3-new-bundled.zip could not be verified as no signature was found.
```

Should I be worried or is it normal?

```
Update WordPress

Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-6.4.3-new-bundled.zip…

The authenticity of wordpress-6.4.3-new-bundled.zip could not be verified as no signature was found.

Unpacking the update…

Verifying the unpacked files…

Preparing to install the latest version…

Enabling Maintenance mode…

Copying the required files…

Disabling Maintenance mode…

Upgrading database…
```

Comment: You might have better luck with this on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com